# How to Add post title to content description?

Tags: php, wordpress

Using this code

```
    <?php
$post = $wp_query->post;
$descrip = strip_tags($post->post_content);
$descrip_more = '';
if (strlen($descrip) > 155) {
$descrip = substr($descrip,0,155);
$descrip_more = ' ...';
}
$descrip = str_replace('"', '', $descrip);
$descrip = str_replace("'", '', $descrip);
$descripwords = preg_split('/[\n\r\t ]+/', $descrip, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
array_pop($descripwords);
$descrip = implode(' ', $descripwords) . $descrip_more; $descrip =  strip_shortcodes($descrip );
echo '<meta name="description" content="'.$descrip.'">'; ?>
```

Which outputs something like this in my header:

```
<meta name="description" content="   Everything year life dont know why but ...">
```

I was wondering if I could add something to the code that would add the single post title before the "Everything year life dont know why but ..." part, at the beginning of the content, so it looks like

Maybe out it like this?

```
<meta name="description" content=" Uverworld - nano second (<-- the post title) Everything year life dont know why but     ...">
```

in other words

```
<meta name="description" content=" Uverworld - nano second Everything year life dont know why but     ...">
```

--

The above code also leaves a lot of spaces before the content and shows up like
    
Is there a way to get rid of that as well?

Comment: Why not put the post title in the `<title>` element?

Comment: It's already there, but for SEO purposes, I'm trying to make a combination in the description for the title, and the description.

Comment: Why do you think that will help SEO?

Comment: It's not that I think it will help with seo, the description metatag is needed so search engines won't take random things on my website and display that as the description, but may I just please know how to do this? like for my own personal reasons? Why does it matter what my reason for doing so is?

Comment: I have answered this on your other question.

Comment: @user2320262 This is just a simple exercise in string concatenation.  I asked you what your intent was in that your attempting to do this will probably actually hurt you from an SEO standpoint. If you want to fill out the description, then fill out the description in your post itself.

Comment: Alright thank you then, if you know though, may you please tell me how to do this? I'd like to take my chances.

Comment: Nevermind nathan I found it! Thank you works perfectly!!

Comment: The PHP function **[trim](http://uk3.php.net/trim)** removes extra spaces from the beginning or end of a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>  Everything year life dont know why but ...">
```