# Unique Meta Description for every single post

Tags: php, html, wordpress, meta

i've try the code on this forum page

[to Add post title to content description?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892642/how-to-add-post-title-to-content-description)

[Stupid WordPress Tricks Perishable Press](http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/01/stupid-wordpress-tricks/#swt_22)

but none of these work.
i want to generate meta description on every single post and every single page.
because when i check my website i got duplicte meta description and meta tag on many page of my website.

i want it like this below, i will create example of article on single post.
website :www*site name*com
meta description =" website for help you "
meta keyword =" help me,help you"

example on single post titled " You need help for something" , 
the url would be "www*sitename*com/blame/you-need-help-for-something/

you need help for something (title)

hel will be provide by someone good in their study, even it is hard there will be imposible if there is none out there will help you.    ( this is first sentence of the article/post)

i want that first article' senteces be my meta description of my single post, so when i checkk my meta description of url "sitename/blame/you-need-help-for-something/

the meta description would be :
"hel will be provide by someone good in their study, even it is hard there will be imposible if there is none out there will help you"

Not :
" website for help you " or event empty

would some one please help me out with this?i all very thanks to :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a plugin this might help you:

http://www.welcomebrand.co.uk/thoughts/dynamic-meta-descriptions-in-wordpress/

If it's a single article or a page it will use the excerpt, else it will use your blog description from your settings. You can also extend it to your needs!

Comment: hmm is this work with wordpres 3.8? i am using it now and i think i'il update to 3.9..
i 've read the artikel from that website (welcomebrand) even there is someone say it didn't work with worpdres 3.5...

and one more thing if i may, i want meta description on "page category" also and i don't want to using plugin..
would you help me one more please

Comment: It will still work if you update to 3.9! It shouldn't make any differnce. Essential is that there's a post on the page you're on, so there will be an excerpt to get.

Comment: and how about meta description on category page?
this excerpt will exsist too when i write cetegory in category page?

Comment: If you're on a category page with all the posts from one category I guess it won't display a description. You could replace "elseif(is_home())" with "else" so it will display the general description on all other pages if it isnt a single post or a page (like archives).

Comment: i check it with "SEO Quake"
on my  single post it work,it grap the some sentence of artikel on single post page as meta description.
but the meta description on homepage and category are empy(there is no meta description)

on webmaster tool HTML improvement, kind of like this is duplicate meta description and title tag, i've trouble with it.
so i want there is none of duplicate meta description and title tag on webmaster tool.

Comment: rather than automatic graph meta description on single post but meta description on homepage and category are the same, i prefer to write it manually if it is to make no duplicate content and title tag.
but i do not want to use plugin